# Using codeblocks writing a c program that repeatedly prompts for input

Tags: c, codeblocks

Key points, I'm using Codeblocks to write this program, and it needs to be written with the intent of writing C only and nothing more. I want it to be as basic as possible. So this is the mess that I  have so far.

I need this program to continue to ask the user for a value until between 1-29 until it reaches 176. Once it exceeds 176 all I need to do is print the sum of the numbers, the largest number entered and the smallest number entered.

From there the program needs to loop and ask if another set of numbers will be entered. Terminating the program with the appropriate user input. I need to output the following info:

- Sum of all numbers
- Largest number entered
- smallest number entered

If anyone has any advice that would help a lot.

```
/* Matthew Gambrell CSC 120 12/4/14*/

#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
  int total, num, large, small, again;

  again=1;

  while (again==1);
  {
    total = 0;
    large = 0;
    small = 50;
  }

  while(total<=176);
  {
    num=inputNum();
    total=tot(num, total);
    large=CheckLarge(num, total);
    small=CheckSmall(num, small);}
    printresult(total, large, small);
    printf("play again");
    printf("1=yes 0=no");
    scanf("%d", &again);
  }

  float inputNum();
  {
    float badnum, num;
    badnum=1;
    while (badnum==1);
      printf("please enter a number between 1 and 29");
      scanf("%f", &num);
    if(num>0 and num<30)
      badnum = 0;
    else
      printf("error renter");
      getch("press enter to continue");
    return(num)
  }

  tot(num, total)
  total += num
  return (total)
}

return(num)
```

Comment: First of all, remove those semicolons after all the `while`, as it is your program is a nice collection of endless loops (`while` repeats the instruction that follows it, and `;` is the "empty instruction").

Comment: You've bitten off a lot more than you can chew. Start with something simple, like get a number from the user and print it out. Hint: given that `num` is an `int` use `%d` in the `scanf`.

Comment: Okay so I'm removing the semicolons after all the while statements. I knew that wasn't right, also if I'm using float wouldn't I want to use %f? I need this program to total up my entered values between 1-29 and =176. Then it will terminate program with the 3 statement outputs sum of all numbers, largest number entered, and smallest number entered. Would I create 3 separate loops for each one? One of my classmates said you almost want to create a loop within a loop which threw me off.

Comment: *"if I'm using float wouldn't I want to use %f?"* Yes, I only saw the declaration of `num` as an `int` at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like your classmate said, you can do this using a loop within a loop. The structure of your code makes it seem like this was your goal.

Firstly, as mentioned in the comments, remove your semicolons from the end of your `while(..);` statements. This will allow control to enter the blocks you're defining below them.

Secondly, you probably want to place the closing bracket for your first `while` loop after the end of your second `while` loop. This is your 'loop within a loop' structure.

Thirdly, you don't have any real way of displaying your results at present. Usually, your `int main(){ ... }` function returns a number relating to how your program went. Whilst you can have it return your `total` variable, it's more likely you want it to `return 0;`, and output your variables to screen during program execution.

For example, as you did in your input parsing in `inputNum(..)`, you can write

```
printf('The total is %i\n', total);
printf('The largest number entered was %i\n', large);
printf('The smallest number entered was %i\n', small);
```

These numbers (`large` and `small`) will need to be within your (first) while loop - they should be reset each time your loop restarts, but not each time you enter a number.

Comment: Okay, great. We haven't used %i yet in any code. What does that do differently then %d or %f?

Comment: `%i` and `%d` are the same - sorry. `%f` is for floating point numbers, eg `float`s. You can add more detail using things like `%2.5f` etc - see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)